# Can I merge two IEnumerable<string> to IEnumerable<string,string>

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have two `IEnumerable<string>`

```
IEnumerable<String> titleCollection = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//h2[@class=
'entry-title']/a").Select(x => x.InnerHtml);

IEnumerable<String> allImages = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=
'entry-thumbnail hover-thumb']/a/img").Select(x => x.Attributes["src"].Value);
```

Is it possible to merge them to single `IEnumerable<HTMLELEmsnts>`.For sure there would be complications, but is there any way.

```
class HTMLElements
    {
        //private string _articeName;

        public string ArticleName { get; set; }
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: under which criteria you´d want to join them?

Comment: @SebastianPiu ,Din't Understand 'which criteria'.Just want to merge  both of them

Comment: @Simsons: he is asking what you mean by "merge". I've posted an answer that assumes one possible meaning. But you could easily mean something entirely different. If my answer doesn't address your question, show an example of the input you expect, and the output you desire to obtain from that.

Comment: It's still not stated clearly but it seems that you have ["parallel arrays"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array). Is that right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no such thing as `IEnumerable<string, string>`. `IEnumerable<T>` has only one type parameter.

But you can use [`Enumerable.Zip<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) to create an `IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>>` or similar.

EDIT:

Based on the updated question, it seems you might want something like this:

```
IEnumerable<HTMLElements> Merge(IEnumerable<string> names, IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    return names.Zip(urls, (name, url) => new HTMLElements(name, url));
}
```